# What should we tell users with questions migrated and without an account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Well, every once in a while, something [like this](https://superuser.com/questions/287626/cannot-find-usb-device-to-mount) happens.

**Question is migrated.**

[image]

User logs in with "another" account and [posts an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/287626/cannot-find-usb-device-to-mount/327709#327709).

[image]

Now, obviously they can neither accept their answer, nor can they reply to other answers, edit their question, et cetera.

What is the easiest way to tell those users what to do?

- Is this the FAQ we should point them to?

  > [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)
- Or is there a simpler way of saying:

  > *user*, in order to re-associate your accounts, you have to *Yada Yada*.

Comment: Most of the time at least one of the accounts is unregistered which fundamentally is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that *they didn't log in at all*.

- on Stack Overflow, registered user with a certain credential
- on Super User, unregistered user

They posted as an anonymous unregistered user. If they don't even attempt to log in, we can't match their accounts.

Basically they need to click "log in" and use a matching credential for this to work.

---

*Update:* if we have any association at all (the user has the same account), we'll correctly match up *all* their content going forward.  In the past if a user was merged after content had been migrated, users on the losing side of the merge were out of luck, since their unique ID changed to the new master and *that's* what we'd be looking for when seeing which posts they should own upon first logging in.

Now, with everything costanzafied, we'll search not only your brand new shiny account ID, but *all previous IDs* as well (any that have been merged in).

For the case in the question, it is possible to recover the post *if you're still "logged in" as the unregistered user* (the owner of the original post) and **register**.  Then, logging into the second site will recover ownership of the post.  If you've cleared cookies, etc, and aren't "logged in" as the unregistered user anymore...we (still) can't really do anything to auto-recover ownership there.

Comment: In the end I'm looking for the simplest way to tell them what to do. How would you put this as a comment? Couldn't there be a case where the user hasn't registered on SO as well?

Comment: if the user didn't register on SO, they're screwed -- we have no way to connect them to the question cross-site.

Comment: So basically, *if they're registered*, tell them to log in, if they're not, just leave it as-is and eventually delete/comment-ify answers?

Comment: yes, log in or register on the *new* site but it only matters if they were previously registered on the *other* site

Comment: So just to make sure: If they are unregistered on the "parent" site (like [here](http://superuser.com/questions/328174/permission-denied-linux-mail-command/328661#328661)), there is **absolutely no way** to ever  gain control of your question anymore?

Comment: yes that is correct, because they never had control before. I'll double check with the team though.

Comment: Did you by chance find out about the process? I just had the [same thing happening again](http://superuser.com/questions/332837/unmounting-detachable-devices-esata-usb-storage-in-linux/332936#332936).

Comment: we are changing the way this works a bit; Nick will be editing this soon with a proper answer reflecting the new state

Comment: @Nick So with a [registration required to ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it/107163#107163), this is more-or-less not an issue anymore, right? (at least for stuff migrated from SO)

Comment: @slhck - true, but only in the SO case...and also not true for already-migrated content that doesn't match the conditions above.  I ran a fairly thorough fix up last night of all accounts/migrations/posts of all old content that we could associate to users (and prepped for future logins/claims of content), so we should be in as good a shape as possible moving forward.

Answer (score 4):

I have thought it would be very helpful to have a notification in the top left that says something like:

> Your *question*[1] was migrated from *(first SE site)*[2] to *(second SE
>   site)*[3]. Please log into *(second SE site)*[4].

where:

- link #1 would say "question" and link to the new question
- link #2 would be the name of the first SE site ("stackoverflow.com" in the questioner's example) and link to that site's home page
- link #3 would be the name of the second SE site ("superuser.com" in the questioner's example) and link to that site's home page
- link #4 would be a link with text of the second site's name that links to the login page on the second SE site

Comment: Good idea! I'm all for a bit more feedback. Maybe even take out #2 and #3, because I can imagine they would confuse. Ultimately, you want users to click on the *Login* link, and not somewhere else (and thereby lose the notification).

Comment: That's true. Maybe leave the notification the same just don't link #2 and #3.

Comment: By the way, you could make this a *real* feature request question here on meta, so you get more input from the community. I think it's a valid request since this is a common problem. Just add a bit of arguments why it would be necessary (e.g. the fact that the current status is just confusing).

Comment: [See this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104177/162637).

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing the latter.

> {User}, if you "associate" the account here with your account at {other Stack Exchange site} you'll regain control of this question.

Comment: But how do I "associate" them? (i.e. what are the steps involved?) How do I put this for a user who hasn't used SE before? Even I myself have a hard time actually understanding the information outlined [in the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste/73801#73801).