# better notification of migrated question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notify Author when Question is migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29344/notify-author-when-question-is-migrated)

I have thought it would be very helpful to have a notification in the top left that says something like:

> Your question(1) was migrated from (first SE site) to (second SE
>   site). Please log into (second SE site)(2).

where:

- **link #1** would say "question" and link to the new question
- **link #2** would be a link with text of the second site's name that links to the login page on the second SE site

This suggestion stems from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103851/what-should-we-tell-users-with-questions-migrated-and-without-an-account/103882#103882). The issue in this question arises when a question is migrated for a user who doesn't have an account on the second site, and, not knowing how SE works, that user makes a second account to post. There needs to be a better notification so users are pushed towards linking all of their SE accounts.

A feature similar to this seems like a no-brainer. Users should be directed to, with succinct instructions, log in to the other SE site with a linked account, and there should be a link to easily get them there.

Comment: How about a drop down message for this?

Comment: Yes, that would make more sense, as it's similar to the "Your answer to ... was migrated to ..." notification or others. [Something like that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iS1id.png)? @mti